# JavaScript disable button when table is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an external Javascript and I want to enable a button when the table is not empty.

But I cannot seem to make it work.

This is my code:

```
 $(function(){
    var rowCount = $('#uploadsTable tbody tr').length;

    if(rowCount != 0){
        document.getElementById("finalizeButton").disabled = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: "*the able is not empty*". What is "able"?

Comment: @dfsq, as per title it is _table_

Comment: Try this `$("#finalizeButton").prop('disabled', false)` instead of `document.getElementById("finalizeButton").disabled = false`

Comment: @bad_boy What is the difference? This is the same.

Comment: Does the table gets filled up or emptied out without reloading the page?

Comment: I have added a solution with working jsfiddle for you. Please let me know what you think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable button:

```
 $('#finalizeButton').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

So your code will be:

```
$(function(){
    var rowCount = $('#uploadsTable tbody tr').length;
    if(rowCount < 1){
        $('#finalizeButton').attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
        $('#finalizeButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: This works! But I had to change the rowCount == 0. Meaning if it's empty, button is disabled, else it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Of course, it has to be below the button, or in `.ready()`:

```
$(function(){
    var rowCount = $('#uploadsTable tbody tr').length;

    if(rowCount == 0){
        document.getElementById("finalizeButton").disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please check following example:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to return the number of tr elements in the table.</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button id = "buy"> Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
   if(x == 0){

      document.getElementById("buy").disabled = true;
    }else{

        document.getElementById("buy").disabled = false;
    }
```